# How to display the pulldown button only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a customize combobox and want to use the default pulldown button used on `<select>` element. The combobox is composed of a textbox, a pulldown button and somewhat a table element containing the list. Everything is working except for displaying dropdown button. 
Note that I want to refrain from using any background image for the button. I want to use the default dropdown button. 
How can I make use of the dropdown button?

Comment: Could you post some example code?

Comment: Yes, *Post teh codez...*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make a `<select>` element, then, using positioning in your stylesheet, cover it with the text field. If you position the textfield right, you should show only the pulldown button from your `<select>`.